# Jupyter Notebook - Python 3 kernel

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook

I have Jupyter Notebook installed and working. However it only has python 2 kernel.

[image: notebook kernel]

I tried reinstalling Anaconda with Python 3.6 version of python, which worked fine (apart from deleting all my environments, etc.), but no change in relation to the kernels available for Jupyter.

I have tried installing jupyter using pip (the solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45106616/how-to-switch-to-python-2-7-from-python-3-jupyter-notebook) question), but I get the error message `Requirement already satisfied: jupyter in c:\users\username\anaconda2\lib\site-packages`

Any ideas?

Comment: @senderle Yes, this is the problem I think. I'm taking a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41862682/how-can-i-use-both-anaconda-versions-2-7-3-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using `pip3 install jupyter`?

a more robust solution would be to isolate your environments with something like pipenv.

```
pip install pipenv

pipenv install --three
```

this will install a virtual environment with python3

install packages

```
pipenv install jupyter
```

activate the env

```
pipenv shell
```

start the notebook

```
jupyter notebook
```

You should be able to see the [python3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Cnd1.png) option now.

Comment: Pip3 wasn't my first choice for a solution to this, but it has been the only successful approach that I've found to add a python 3 kernel to jupyter notebook